Retrieving Latest BLOB (Excel File) for Power BI in Oracle
I hope you all are doing well. I have a question regarding working with BLOB data in Oracle and Power BI.
I have several Excel files stored as BLOBs within a table named GENERATED_FILES in my Oracle database. I'd like to automatically retrieve the latest inserted file and make it accessible for reading within Power BI.
I've explored various methods but haven't found a successful solution yet. Could someone provide guidance on crafting a SQL query that I can use in Power BI to achieve this?
Here's the table schema for GENERATED_FILES  image
